# Using an array with jQuery's .not()

Tags: jquery, arrays

What I'm trying to learn is how to use an array with .not() in jQuery. My code is below. Do you know why .item-ii is not being excluded from the selection? Thanks in advance!

```
<ul class="level-1">
  <li class="item-i">I</li>
  <li class="item-ii">II
    <ul class="level-2">
      <li class="item-a">A</li>
      <li class="item-b">B
        <ul class="level-3">
          <li class="item-1">1</li>
          <li class="item-2">2</li>
          <li class="item-3">3</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="item-c">C</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="item-iii">III</li>
</ul>
<script>
    var temp = new Array();
    temp[0] = '.item-ii';
    console.log(temp);
    $('li').not(temp).css('background', 'red');
</script>
```

Comment: `('li').not(temp[0]).css('background', 'red');`

Comment: @pXL +1 to your comment. I must add that before using an array to define the items you want to exclude, you must know how to get an array item.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you need to *exclude all the selectors in the `temp` array*, you can do:

```
$('li').not(temp.join(',')).css('background', 'red');
```

For example if `temp = ['.item-ii', '.item-i']`, the above will be equivalent to:

```
$('li').not('.item-ii,.item-i').css('background', 'red');
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you need to specify the array element, not the entire array.

```
$('li').not(temp[0]).css('background', 'red');
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/yEbnG/)**

Update:

To do this with multiple elements, try (note the removal of the period before the class name in your array):

```
 var temp = new Array();
 temp[0] = 'item-ii';
 $('li').not(function () {
     return ($.inArray($(this).attr('class'), temp) > -1);
 }).css('background', 'red');
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/yEbnG/3/)**

Comment: What if I had 4 elements in the array? How would I exclude the entire array without specifying each element individually?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question "*Do you know why .item-ii is not being excluded from the selection?*"

When you supply the array as the selector, jQuery uses `$.grep()`...

[.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/)

```
not: function( selector ) {
    return this.pushStack( winnow(this, selector, false), "not", selector);
},
```

[winnow()](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js)

```
function winnow( elements, qualifier, keep ) {

    // Can't pass null or undefined to indexOf in Firefox 4
    // Set to 0 to skip string check
    qualifier = qualifier || 0;

    if ( jQuery.isFunction( qualifier ) ) {
        return jQuery.grep(elements, function( elem, i ) {
            var retVal = !!qualifier.call( elem, i, elem );
            return retVal === keep;
        });

    } else if ( qualifier.nodeType ) {
        return jQuery.grep(elements, function( elem ) {
            return ( elem === qualifier ) === keep;
        });

    } else if ( typeof qualifier === "string" ) {
        var filtered = jQuery.grep(elements, function( elem ) {
            return elem.nodeType === 1;
        });

        if ( isSimple.test( qualifier ) ) {
            return jQuery.filter(qualifier, filtered, !keep);
        } else {
            qualifier = jQuery.filter( qualifier, filtered );
        }
    }

    return jQuery.grep(elements, function( elem ) {
        return ( jQuery.inArray( elem, qualifier ) >= 0 ) === keep;
    });
}
```

...which compares the DOM node against your string - which has to fail of course :)

So you would have to add the DOM elements which should be excluded and not only their selector.

```
var temp = $(".item-ii").map(function() {
        return this;
    });
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/H3TsP/)

So you should better use one of the other answers to get the effect you want :)